# OWLAPI : Create new Reasoner (HermiT)

Tags: java, ontology, owl-api

I want to create new reasoner (HermiT).

What is the difference between following two approaches :-

1) *Using Factory* : [org.semanticweb.HermiT.ReasonerFactory]

```
ReasonerFactory factory = new ReasonerFactory();
OWLReasoner reasoner =  factory.createReasoner(ontology, configuration);
```

2) *Using constructor* : [org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner]

```
Reasoner reasoner = new Reasoner(configuration, ontology);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factory might carry out more initialization steps - depends on the reasoner.

In HermiT's case there is no difference. However, the constructor might change between versions; the factory is an owlapi interface and therefore it will give you a seamless interface if you move to a different HermiT version.

Comment: What is the difference between OWLReasoner interface and Reasoner class ? Do Reasoner class implements OWLReasoner interface ?

Comment: Yes, Reasoner implements OWLReasoner